# Oracle 11g to PostgreSQL - CREATE TYPE OBJECT

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle11g

How can I make this `Oracle 11g` piece of `SQL` work on `PostgreSQL`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GeoCoord AS OBJECT (
 Longitude NUMBER,
 Latitude NUMBER);
```

Comment: If you mean "*make this statement work **without** any change*" in Postgres, then the answer is a clear: no. You will need to change the SQL so that Postgres understands it. If you are just trying to create a user defined type, then see the manual for `CREATE TYPE`

Comment: I want to know the PostgreSQL equivalent to the query above. PostgreSQL documentation doens't have the object output type so that is why I'm asking here.

Comment: It's the link that Onur already posted: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html `CREATE TYPE geocord as (longitude decimal, latitude decimal);` Or use the built-in type `point` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6730

Comment: ok thanks it seems to work. If you see the examples they always give some sort of type after TYPE like ENUM or RANGE that's why I was confused.

Comment: [The very first example is:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html#AEN77691) `CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (f1 int, f2 text);` no `object`, not `range` no `enum`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not use but you can use like this;

[Create Type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html)

or you can find it in

[Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html)

Comment: You can use CREATE TYPE on PostgreSQL, the problem is that the OBJECT it's not recognized.

Comment: Also i find same question in; [link](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21793.1243183338@sss.pgh.pa.us)

Comment: @mexzr: that **does** answer your question. There is no `object` keyword for a Postgres `TYPE`.

Comment: I know that. That's why I'm asking if there is an equivalent query or what should I use instead of OBJECT...

Comment: @mexzr: sorry I don't understand you. The manual clearly shows the syntax to create the equivalent thing. Postgres doesn't use the keyword `OBJECT`. Why do you think you need that?